# How can I delete the contents of a folder with PHP?

Tags: php

I can't seem to get this function to delete all my files and folders in a specific directory can someone help me fix this problem?

Here is my code.

```
$apps = 9;
$dirname = './members/' . $apps . '/';
function delete_directory($dirname) {
   if (is_dir($dirname))
      $dir_handle = opendir($dirname);
   if (!$dir_handle)
      return false;
   while($file = readdir($dir_handle)) {
      if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
         if (!is_dir($dirname."/".$file))
            unlink($dirname."/".$file);
         else
            delete_directory($dirname.'/'.$file);    
      }
   }
   closedir($dir_handle);
   rmdir($dirname);
   return true;
}
```

Comment: What happens when you try running it? What errors do you encounter? Does the user your PHP script is running as have permissions to delete the files?

Comment: yes I have permission, but nothing happens no error no nothing.

Comment: Your function looks fine..are you sure you are **calling** it right ?

Comment: @codaddict maybe I'm calling it wrong how should I do it correctly?

Comment: You can call is as: `delete_directory($dirname);` after you set the value of `$dirname` in line 2.

Comment: @codaddict your a life saver thanks it works now.

Comment: @sleep: I've added my comment as an answer as not all users read the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function looks fine.

I guess you are not ***calling*** it correctly. One way to call it is:

```
$apps = 9;
$dirname = './members/' . $apps . '/';
delete_directory($dirname);

function delete_directory($dirname) {
.....
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function EmptyDir($dir) 
{
    $handle=opendir($dir);
    while (($file = readdir($handle))!==false) {
        unlink($dir.'/'.$file);
    }
    closedir($handle);
}

EmptyDir('yourdir');
```

Answer (score 0):

Should the initial directory have a trailing slash?

```
$dirname = './members/' . $apps;
```

Comment: That is fine. You can have any number of consecutive `/` in a path. For example: `"foo/bar"` is same as `"foo///////bar"`